# css dropdown menu hover with all drop downs

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have this css menu on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DenErello/pQhpu/

css:

```
.Menu {
background-color: #3b69a2;
height: 30px;
}
.Menu, .Menu li {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.Menu li {
float: left;
width: 100px;
display: block;
line-height: 30px;
}
.Menu ul {
opacity: 0;
}
.Menu ul li {
line-height: 20px;
background-color: #3b69a2;
}
.Menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
```

html:

```
<ul class="Menu">
<li>Test 1
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1.1</li>
        <li>Test 1.2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Test 2
    <ul>
        <li>Test 2.1</li>
        <li>Test 2.2</li>
        <li>Test 2.3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now, this works great and all. But what I want is to see both drop down menus after going on 1 of the main menu items. I can't quite figure it out, anyone on how to do this? And in addition I'd like to see a full 100% width background with it and full height of the dropdown as the biggest dropdown. I tried with background and all on ul but it seems like it doesn't work

Comment: Why bother using a list at all when you want the menu item to act as a single element, and the same with the sub-item? It's easy if you simply use nested divs, but then it's not much of a navigation aid.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I really understand, but what if you use the hover property on .Menu ? So that you have both menus display when you have your mouse over the whole area ?

```
.Menu:hover li ul { opacity: 1; }
```

Then, to have the full width, I would add the following rule :

```
.Menu:hover{height:auto;overflow:hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQhpu/5/

Otherwise, I would second isherwood and say you need some javascript.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution which fits my needs the most. I'm think i'm changing the way of thinking in my menu. I'm going to use a div version: http://jsfiddle.net/DenErello/r35Tg/1/

and then use a list in the first dive for main items and in the second div the others

Comment: Glad it helps, don't forget to tag the answer if it is the most appropriate ;), cheers

Answer (score 1):

No javascript needed, add this to your css:

```
.Menu:hover ul { opacity: 1; }
```

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/pQhpu/4/

Comment: And there it is, folks. Nice. I guess my brain just refused to let me treat the menu as one big item.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks. Yes had to think "slightly out of the box" for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first top-level item triggering both sub-menus with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pQhpu/1/

```
.Menu li:hover + li ul { opacity: 1; }
```

It doesn't work on the second top-level item because the adjacent sibling selector only applies to following siblings. You'll need JavaScript for this. It's easy with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with jQuery. Unless there's a reason you're using `opacity` to hide and show the dropdowns, I'd recommend using `display` instead.

```
var menuItem = $(".Menu").children("li");

menuItem.on("mouseenter", function() {
  menuItem.children("ul").show();
});

menuItem.on("mouseleave", function() {
  menuItem.children("ul").hide();
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/pQhpu/3/).

Comment: The reason behind opacity is no reason then learning from tutorials on the internet about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Menu li.main:hover ~ li > ul {
    opacity:1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQhpu/6/)

I think your code needs a dose of this.