# Please help me with this navigation bar

Tags: html, css

this is my code for the vertical navigation bar that I have created, there is one more thing that I need to add here and that is flyout menu on mouse over. I have tried many things but it did not work. 
Here's my CSS CODE

```css
.navbar{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
width: 280px; /* width of menu */
}

.navbar li{
border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* white border beneath each menu item */
}

.navbar li a{
background: #333 url(media/sexypanelright.gif) no-repeat right top; /*color of menu by default*/
font: bold 13px "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;
display: block;
color: white;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 0; /* Vertical (top/bottom) padding for each menu link */
text-indent: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*bottom border of menu link. Should be equal or darker to link's bgcolor*/
}

.navbar li a:visited, .navbar li a:active{
color: white;
}

.navbar li a:hover{
background-color: black; /*color of menu onMouseover*/
color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*bottom border of menu link during hover. Should be            equal or darker to link's hover's bgcolor*/
}
```

and the html part is this

```html
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="#">»  Computers</a>

</li>
<li><a href="#" >»  Networking Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#/">»  Security Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Office Automations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Projectors and Display     Screens</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Peripherals and Components</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Softwares</a></li> 
<li class="lastitem"><a href="#">»  Customized Solutions</a></li>       
</ul>
```

what I want is that when the user hovers his mouse on any of the item in this list then a flyout menu appears with a menu. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778678/css-dropdown-menu-hover-with-all-drop-downs

Comment: That is for a drop-down menu sir, I want it for a flyout menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPRzA/)

This is the key, when you hover the li, the child with the class .flyout will be visible

```css
.navbar li:hover .flyout {
    display: block;
}
```

PS: I only added a submenu for the first two voices in the main menu to keep the code short

Comment: You're terrible at using stackoverflow.
First: the title "Please help me with this navigation bar" doesn't say anything about the question you're asking
Second: You should provide a fiddle so the people who are trying to help you don't have to.
Third: "Its still not working" doesn't help. What is not working? What is the seen behaviour and what is the expected behaviour? Help us help you!

Comment: The expected behavior as I said would be a fly-out menu coming out of the vertical navigation bar when the user does mouse over on the parent list's item, a sub-list should appear that has a width of approximately 280px and height depending upon the number of elements.
 I know I am terrible but all I was asking for was a little bit of help cos I am new with web-designing.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested it on chrome, firefox and Safari and it works for me. Please note that I added a sub navigation only to "computers" and "Network solutions".

Comment: you also created a sub-list in the parent list?
  like this <ul class="navbar">
            <li>Computer
            <ul><li>
            Asus
            </ul>
            </ul>

Comment: Yes, I did. Look at the simplified answer from Sam R. and see if after that my version makes more sense. Do you see it working, now?

Comment: Yes its working now and yes your code is simpler, I guess I was too worked out to understand that, thanks a lot for letting me eat your head.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is actually very simple. Add an extra unordered list `ul` *after* the list `li` element that you want a submenu on. For example, say you wanted a submenu only on "Network Solutions" your html would look like this:

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">»  Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >»  Networking Solutions</a>
        <ul>
          <li>This is a submenu item</li>
          <li>Another submenu item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <li><a href="#/">»  Security Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»  Office Automations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»  Gadgets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»  Projectors and Display     Screens</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»  Peripherals and Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">»  Softwares</a></li> 
    <li class="lastitem"><a href="#">»  Customized Solutions</a></li>       
</ul>
```

Then in your css, you need to set the `ul` *after* the first `ul` and `li` item to `display:none` so that it doesnt show. Then set the hover psuedo to `display:block` or inline depending on your needs. Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aqDD/2/) of what it should look like. Obviously a simple example, but it makes the point.

Comment: There is only one last problem and that is when I mouse over the item in the main list, then a gap is formed between the consecutive items, the flyout menu works perfectly but is there any way to remove that gap?

Comment: yes, the first `ul` has to be positioned relative, and the second `ul` (`ul li ul`) has to be positioned absolute. Make sure you set the `left:` property to the width of the first `ul` so it doesn't overlap. This is a great article on positioning and when to use which value: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101